# GROUP BY not working when I run the following: SELECT jobtitle, salary, COUNT(*) FROM employees GROUP BY salary;

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

After creating a testing DB and tables for sql queries I see that from a tutorial that the following should bring up tables but when ran I get an error:

```
SELECT jobtitle, salary, COUNT(*) FROM employees GROUP BY salary;
```

> ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'company.employees.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

This is not the case when I remove the jobtitle

Why is jobtitle not a valid expression for group by when running my query?

Comment: The keys in the `GROUP BY` need to match the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.

Comment: If there really is a tutorial that doesn't include in the GROUP BY all non-aggregated columns in the SELECT then it might be time to find a better tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, mysql, unlike most other sql servers, has allowed arbitrary fields to be selected when using group by.  In your example, jobtitle would be returned from some arbitrary one of the employees rows for the returned salary.  There's no guarantee that it would even be the same for a given salary between two runs of the query.

Since this is a common source of bugs, mysql has moved away from allowing this, first allowing opting in to stricter validation and then making it the default.  This is controlled by the SQL_MODE system variable.  You can revert to the old, bad way by doing `set session sql_mode=replace(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','');` before your query.

But it is better to follow the stricter rules.  You can tell your query explicitly how to find a non-arbitrary jobtitle for each salary, like:

```
SELECT MIN(jobtitle) AS jobtitle, salary, COUNT(*) FROM employees GROUP BY salary;
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(jobtitle) AS jobtitle, salary, COUNT(*) FROM employees GROUP BY salary;
```

or you can simply group by both, potentially returning multiple rows for a given salary when there is more than one jobtitle for that salary:

```
SELECT jobtitle, salary, COUNT(*) FROM employees GROUP BY salary, jobtitle;
```

Comment: Thank you for all the detail and the sql query examples. I took the last one and tried it and it works. I have not gotten into min and max in my studying but this is useful for my notes  I am making on github

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to care while writing GROUPBY clause in queries is that:

1. Only attributes which appear in GROUPBY can be used with SELECT keyword.
2. Aggregate functions like **count,min,max,avg**,etc. can be used after SELECT keyword.

So, the correct query will be,

> SELECT jobtitle, salary, COUNT(*) FROM employees GROUP BY salary, jobtitle;

Comment: I think point 1 is poorly defined above, to the point of being misleading

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I used the query you provided as it was the same as the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your `group by` clause must contain all the attributes you add in `select` statement with aggregate function.

So your query should be

```
SELECT jobtitle, salary, COUNT(*) FROM employees GROUP BY salary,jobtitle;
```